# Как запустить сервис в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сервисы, android-threads

Имею два сервиса для уведомлений и воспроизведения аудио. Пробовал использовать `IntentService`, но работало не корректно и насколько я понял, `startForegroundService()` доступен только в android >= 8.

Также знаю, что можно использовать `Thread` или `Handler`, но не имею представления как организовать это, так как не нашел подходящих примеров.

А именно, где организовывать новый поток в самом сервисе, или в активности, или как-то по другому?

Логи для ответа

```
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/System.out: StartService
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/System.out: Destroy
// проверка кнопки
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/System.out: StartService
// запуск, далее сворачивание приложения
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@fa672d7[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=68
I/mali_egl: eglDestroySurface() in
I/mali_winsys: delete_surface() [1080x2340] return
I/mali_egl: eglDestroySurface() out
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7760d9af50 disconnect failed
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)8 dur=10 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@36c1a31[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
// в течении минуты
I/System.out: Destroy
```

Comment: можете уточнить, что значит "работет не корректно"? и ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Wlad Поместил код который раньше запускал в onStartCommand() в onHandleIntent() и ничего не выполняется. Так же IntentService не предназначен для длительных задач и хотелось бы организовать полноценный сервис.

Comment: Странно, останавливается приложение и через минуту сервис. Почему через минуту? Надо самому погонять сервисы с потоками, хотя еще недавно все было хорошо )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Именно в течении 0.5-1.5 минут.  Например, если использовать это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160441/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5 , то сервис работает на протяжении 20-30 минут

Comment: Не знаю, надо погуглить

Comment: Погодите, а где вы создаете бродкасты? Если что, их надо создавать в созданном вами потоке, иначе зачем он вообще нужен :)

Comment: Уже решил проблему с помощью способа выше по ссылке, там у меня в одном из сервисов не было уведомления. Бродкасты в потоке были, но все ровно ломались

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением для меня стал этот ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground/46449975#46449975

Это нужно добавить в `onCreate()`

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

Если у вас есть свои уведомления, то вы можете завершать это уведомление в `onStartCommand()` так:

```
stopForeground(true);
```

Да, это не очень красиво, но без вибрации и сигнала не заметно (пропадет через секунду). И не забудьте заменить создание уведомлений в вашем сервисе на

```
startForeground(123, notification);
```

Без этого работать на версиях `>= api 26` не будет. Но возможно есть и другой способ.

Answer (score 2):

При помощи Thread вот так:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Thread myThread = new MyThread();

    public MyService() {
        super();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Если поток не запущен, то запустить
        if (!myThread.isAlive())
            myThread.start();

        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    // Поток
    private class MyThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Делаем что-то долгое и нудное/нужное
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, а взаимодействие с ним будет возможно?

Comment: @Shadowlight конечно, все как обычно

Comment: Сделал все как у вас, но при сворачивании приложения в течении минуты сервис выполняет onDestroy(). Возможно я в манифесте еще что-то должен прописать или запускать не через startService()?

Comment: @Shadowlight ну и пусть выполняет, поток работает? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru

Comment: Я убрал завершение задач из onDestroy() и они продолжили работу, но теперь взаимодействие становится невозможным. Например с сервисом уведомлений, так же я использую broadcastReceiver'ы и они все ломаются

Comment: Я имел ввиду onDestroy() сервисов и выполняется он сам при сворачивании приложения. Я попробовал убрать stopService() из onDestroy() активности, но сервисы по прежнему завершают работу

Comment: Нагрузки на устройство нет, возможно сервис с активностью связать нужно, это может быть проблемой?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос логи из тестового приложения, могу скинут исходник