# Создаст ли этот способ уведомление

Tags: java, android

Делаю `foreground service`. В поисках решения нашел это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46449975/12239446

Код:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

После этого моя проблема решена, но создаст ли он не нужное мне уведомление? Так же имею отдельный сервис со своими для плеера.

Comment: В моем случае ничего не создается, но возможно ли на других устройствах? С другой версией андроида или вроде

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста то что находится по ссылке в тело вопроса.